# How to create a virtual host that works with both http and https?

Tags: apache, http, amazon-ec2, https, vhosts

My config is:

```
Listen 443 http
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
ServerName *:80

<VirtualHost *:80> 
  [some non-ssl stuff]
  ServerName account.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443> 
  [some non-ssl stuff(directory, docroot)] 
  ServerName account.example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /Users/myusername/certs/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /Users/myusername/certs/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

So I can't access the http version of my site, but ssl version is working correctly. I want to use both vhosts, http(80) and https(443) to rewrite http to https URL via mod_rewrite.

```
uname -a
Linux 3.4.62-53.42.amzn1.x86_64 GNU/Linux

httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix)
```

Please help to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What does it mean you cannot access the non-ssl version of your website? Does it mean you ever get the URL you receive another content, such as the default content or an other case?

Comment: So, it means that I'm getting message tthat says "Mozilla cannot establish connection with example.com". However, I found by netstat that apache listen only 443 port.
If I add Listen 80 directive, apache don't start.

Comment: In _error_log_:
`Server should be SSL-aware but has no sertificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)`

Comment: The problem belongs to binding the port 80. When another process already listens on port 80 and you start apache also listening on port 80, apache fails during the start time. Check what is already running on port 80 by commnad 'netstat -nltp' (to see PIDs you have to be logged as root). Probably another instance of apache or nginx or other is running on port 80.

Comment: No, there is not any listening process on port 80.
It doesn't start because apache says to log:
`Server should be SSL-aware but has no sertificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)`

Comment: Cannot answer to my question, but I found solution. I add http vhost with SSLEngine off. Will post my answer later. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, my config now is:

```
Listen 443 http
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
ServerName *:80

<VirtualHost *:443> 
  [some non-ssl stuff(directory, docroot)] 
  ServerName account.example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /Users/myusername/certs/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /Users/myusername/certs/server.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  SSLEngine off
  [other stuff like docroot]
</VirtualHost>
```

Not sure about `SSLEngine off`, but now it works. So, I add rewrite rule to redirrect from http to https in http vhost's .htaccess file:

```
#Redirrect from http to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: in which conf file we have to change? vhost? ot httpd/ssl?